# Style for ActionLink in Asp.net Mvc is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui

I am working on Asp.Net Mvc.There is an Action Link. I tried to give style like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login","Login",new {@style = "color:Red"})
```

But it fails. Please advice.

Comment: **How** does it fail? What's the generated source?

Comment: If the link is visited your browser stylesheet may override the style unless you specify a specific color for visited links in your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling [`ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, Object routeValues)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

The last parameter affects the URL, not the HTML attributes.

You need to use the [bigger overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) that takes a second object of HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated as

@Html.ActionLink("Login","Login","Default",null,new {@style = "color:Red;"})

This worked for me.